# Trigger onbeforeunload if form is not submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeload

I've got a form which is being submitted via PHP with 3 submit actions:

- Save and Continue
- Save and Exit
- Exit without Saving

I'd like to trigger an "OnBeforeUnload" alert to display if the user DOES NOT click on any of the form actions to advise them that they're leaving the page, and their changes may not be saved.

I've tried the following code but it seems as though the unbeforeunload is being triggered before my click event. Any suggestions on how best to achieve this?

```
$buttonpressed = false;
$j(".Actions input").click(function(){
    $buttonpressed = true;                                  
});

if(!$buttonpressed){
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        return "Your changes may not be saved.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to do the check *inside* the handler, like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(!$buttonpressed){
        return "Your changes may not be saved.";
    }
}
```

Currently it's binding `window.onbeforeunload` when your code is run because `$buttonpressed` is `false` when it runs...it doesn't matter if it changes later since you already bound the handler.  An alternative is to make it a bit simpler, like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Your changes may not be saved.";
}
$j(".Actions input").click(function(){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

This just removes the handler on `click` instead.  A more appropriate event to handle other submit cases would be to attach to the `submit` event, like this:

```
$j(".myForm").submit(function(){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

Comment: The last option didn't work for me, onbeforeunload was called before the submit event. Fixed it with an onClick over the submit button, and a variable. Thanks!