# window.onbeforeunload alert in case of click of submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code to handle to prompt user in case of unsaved form data  but this code also showing alert in case of click of submit button

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _isDirty = false;
    $(":input").live("change", function () {
        _isDirty = true;
    });

    $(':[type=submit]').live('click', function () {
        _isDirty = false;            
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (_isDirty) {            
            return 'You have made changes to data on this page.  If you navigate away from this page without first saving your data, the changes will be lost.';
        }
        else {           
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: get event and use preventDefault

Comment: Can you check if the code _isDirty = false is actually executed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172671/trigger-onbeforeunload-if-form-is-not-submitted) for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`onbeforeunload` has a quirk that if you return anything, even null, it will throw the alert.  Try removing the else clause `else {return null;}`, and it should stop showing up.