# Using onbeforeunload:

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

```
<script>window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Sure?"; }</script>
```

I don't want it to ask if they select the "add comment" button... it's basically a reminder for if they begin to navigate away without adding the comment.. any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Is it causing conflict because i already have an onClick event?

```
<input type='button' value='Clear' onClick="setval('CATEGORY',''); 
document.getElementById('CATNAME').innerHTML = '';">
```

Thanks in advance, I'm new to stackoverflow so lay it on me if necessary. ; ]

Comment: So your saying that you don't want the onbeforeunload to fire when you submit the form, only when you navigate away without submitting?

Comment: Thanks for asking Mike, to clarify, yes, that's exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out this post: [Trigger onbeforeunload if form is not submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172671/trigger-onbeforeunload-if-form-is-not-submitted)

You can set onbeforeunload to null when your form is submitted.